# Печать html таблицы с постраничной разбивкой

Tags: html, печать

Здравствуйте! Необходимое **кроссбраузерное** решение.

Встала задача печати **длинных** таблиц, по ширине они влазят на лист формата А4 в альбомной ориентации, нужно сделать так, чтобы при определенных условиях отдельно взятые строки (тег &lt;tr&gt;) **переносились на новую страницу**. Вариант с разными таблицами на каждую новую страницу не подходит, т.к. ширина столбцов на всех страницах должна быть **одинаковой**.

Варианты с **page-break-*** по разбивке таблиц работают только в браузерах Opera, и исходя из комментария, написанного [здесь](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp), табличные разрывы не работают в таблицах, и их просто не рекомендуется использовать.

Comment: Как вариант используйте PDF для отображения таких таблиц, в файле PDF длинные таблицы можно разбивать на разные страницы и это решение должно работать в любом браузере, если стоит плагин отображения PDF файлов.

Comment: Спасибо, но вариант с PDF пока не подходит, заказчик хочет, чтобы это было сделано средствами html

Comment: <br style="page-break-after: always">

Answer (score 1):

Нарисовать длинную таблицу на нужное кол-во страниц и заводить данные в определенные строки таблицы, которые расположены уже на другой странице (вычислить, имея некую константу - высоту таблицы в строках на страницу) и обводить только те строки, в которых есть данные.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо за Ваш вариант, но увы, он не подходит, т.к. на этих страницах в тех местах, где позволяет свободное пространство, нужно вставлять дополнительные отдельные информационные блоки, а так-же, печать заголовков и оглавления на каждой новой странице

Comment: colspan и rowspan вам в этом помогут)))

Comment: Неееее, Я сделал по-другому, Я начал считать размеры строк таблиц в пикселях, суммировать их, если размер просуммированных строк превышает заранее подобранное значение, тогда то, что просуммировали добавляем в новую таблицу, и выводим на страницу, а для остальных сбрасываем счетчик размера строк. Каждой из таблиц присвоено значение page-break-before: always